# Enviar array de objetos por ajax al controlador en laravel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel-8

Hola quisiera su ayuda para poder pasar un array desde ajax (jquery) hacia el controlador de un proyecto laravel.

Esta es la funcion donde capturo los valores de un input.

function cost_material() {

```
let dataMaterial = [];
let tbody = document.getElementById('list-materials');
let rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let object = {};
    
    object.material_id = document.getElementsByClassName('material_id')[i].value;
    object.total_material = document.getElementsByClassName('total_material')[i].value;
    object.sale_price = document.getElementsByClassName('sale_price')[i].value;       
   
    dataMaterial.push(object);    
    
    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:'/productos/material',
        data:dataMaterial,           
        statusCode:{
            200:function(response){
                console.log(response['success']);
            },
            500:function(){
                console.log('Error');
            }
        }
    });        
}
```

}

Ahora este es el controller donde quiero recibir el array para poder iterarlo y enviarlo nuevamente al ajax.

public function showCostMaterial(Request $request){

```
    $response = ['data' => null ,'status' => 500];

    $material = $request->dataMaterial;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($material);$i++){
        try{
            if($material[$i]->material_id == 1){
                $costo_total = $request->total_material * $request->sale_price;
                $response['data'] = $costo_total;
                $response['status'] = 200;
            }
            if($material[$i]->material_id == 2){
                $costo_total = $request->total_material * $request->sale_price;
                $response['data'] = $costo_total;
                $response['status'] = 200;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            Log::error('error al obtener datos: ' . $e->getTrace() . ' ' . $e->getMessage());
        }        
    }       
    
    return response()->json(['success' => $response['data'], 'status' => $response['status']]);

}
```

Por alguna razon paso el array lo itero pero no me devuelve valor, incluso cuando pruebo con estas pequeñas lineas para saber si estoy recibiendo el array en el controller.

public function showCostMaterial(Request $request){

```
    $response = ['data' => null ,'status' => 500];

    
    $material = $request->dataMaterial;
    
  
    return response()->json(['success' => $material]);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta puede ser una opcion

```
var objetos = [
        {id: 1, nombre: 'objeto1'},
        {id: 2, nombre: 'objeto2'},
        {id: 3, nombre: 'objeto3'}
    ];

$.ajax({
    url: '/ruta-de-laravel',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {objetos: objetos},
    dataType:'JSON',
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },,
    success: function(data) {
        // Manejar la respuesta del servidor
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Manejar el error
    }
});
```

Para iterarlo en el controlador, debes iterarlo como si fuera un array, en este ejemplo solo se imprimirá el primero en el success del ajax

```
foreach ($request->objetos as $key => $value) {
     return $value['nombre']; 
}
```